# Core plot Multi-line x axis labels

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I have a core plot graph, with the days 1-31 on the x-axis for the days of the month. I need a capitalized first letter (of the day of the week to appear below each n.o

I.E:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

M T W T F S S

I've achieved it by going "1\nM" but the line height is too big, so the letters are too far below.

Does anyone know how I could achieve a close area between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for changing the line spacing right now. You can request an enhancement on the [Core Plot issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).

A workaround would be to render each label into an image with the appearance you want and then use those images to create custom axis labels.